# Integral on a set E

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to calculate $$\int_E (3x+2y)\;dx dy$$ with $$E=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x \in [0,\pi], \min\{4-x,3x\}\le y \le \max \{4-x,3x\} \}$$

It's right: $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{3x}^{4-x}(3x+2y)\;dy\right)dx+\int_{1}^{\pi}\left(\int_{4-x}^{3x}(3x+2y)\;dy\right)dx$$

Comment: Your setup looks correct.

Comment: It's correct. ${}$

Comment: Your answer is also correct.

Comment: the result is ${20 (\pi)^3 \over 3}-2(\pi)^2-16\pi+{68 \over 3}$